# Position a button in the context cell menu

Tags: excel, button, position, office-js, contextmenu

I have developped an Excel Web addin working correctly. It defines in the xml one menu control for the context cell menu. How is it possible to define a position for this button in the menu?

Comment: Please show the manifest XML for this ExtensionPoint.

Answer (score 0):

please check here,https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/manifest-element-ordering. As I know, you can only insert to the end of the existing tab as one new group, or totally add one new tab with new group

Comment: My question is about context cell menu not custom tab

Answer (score 0):

@RickKirkham  `

```
                        <Control xsi:type="Menu" id="Autre2" >
                            <Label resid="Contoso.TaskpaneButton.Label2" />
                            <Supertip>
                                <Title resid="Contoso.TaskpaneButton.Label2"  />
                                <Description resid="Contoso.TaskpaneButton.Tooltip"  />
                            </Supertip>
                            <Icon>
                                <bt:Image size="16" resid="Contoso.No$_16x16" />
                                <bt:Image size="20" resid="Contoso.No$_20x20" />
                                <bt:Image size="24" resid="Contoso.No$_24x24" />
                                <bt:Image size="32" resid="Contoso.No$_32x32" />
                                <bt:Image size="40" resid="Contoso.No$_40x40" />
                                <bt:Image size="80" resid="Contoso.No$_80x80" />
                            </Icon>
                            <Items>
                                <Item id="actionA">
                                    <Label resid="residLabel5"/>
                                    <Supertip>
                                        <Title resid="residLabel" />
                                        <Description resid="residToolTip" />
                                    </Supertip>
                                    <Icon>
                                        <bt:Image size="16" resid="Contoso.couper_16x16" />
                                        <bt:Image size="20" resid="Contoso.couper_20x20" />
                                        <bt:Image size="24" resid="Contoso.couper_24x24" />
                                        <bt:Image size="32" resid="Contoso.couper_32x32" />
                                        <bt:Image size="40" resid="Contoso.couper_40x40" />
                                        <bt:Image size="80" resid="Contoso.couper_80x80" />
                                    </Icon>
                                    <Action xsi:type="ExecuteFunction">
                                        <FunctionName>action5</FunctionName>
                                    </Action>
                                </Item>
                                <Item id="ActionB">
                                    <Label resid="residLabel1"/>
                                    <Supertip>
                                        <Title resid="residLabel" />
                                        <Description resid="residToolTip" />
                                    </Supertip>
                                    <Icon>
                                        <bt:Image size="16" resid="Contoso.Copier_16x16" />
                                        <bt:Image size="20" resid="Contoso.Copier_20x20" />
                                        <bt:Image size="24" resid="Contoso.Copier_24x24" />
                                        <bt:Image size="32" resid="Contoso.Copier_32x32" />
                                        <bt:Image size="40" resid="Contoso.Copier_40x40" />
                                        <bt:Image size="80" resid="Contoso.Copier_80x80" />
                                    </Icon>
                                    <Action xsi:type="ExecuteFunction">
                                        <FunctionName>action6</FunctionName>
                                    </Action>
                                </Item>
                                <Item id="ActionC">
                                    <Label resid="residLabel2"/>
                                    <Supertip>
                                        <Title resid="residLabel" />
                                        <Description resid="residToolTip" />
                                    </Supertip>
                                    <Icon>
                                        <bt:Image size="16" resid="Contoso.Coller_16x16" />
                                        <bt:Image size="20" resid="Contoso.Coller_20x20" />
                                        <bt:Image size="24" resid="Contoso.Coller_24x24" />
                                        <bt:Image size="32" resid="Contoso.Coller_32x32" />
                                        <bt:Image size="40" resid="Contoso.Coller_40x40" />
                                        <bt:Image size="80" resid="Contoso.Coller_80x80" />
                                    </Icon>
                                    <Action xsi:type="ExecuteFunction">
                                        <FunctionName>action7</FunctionName>
                                    </Action>
                                </Item>
                                <Item id="ActionD">
                                    <Label resid="residLabel4"/>
                                    <Supertip>
                                        <Title resid="residLabel" />
                                        <Description resid="residToolTip" />
                                    </Supertip>
                                    <Icon>
                                        <bt:Image size="16" resid="Contoso.Supprimer_16x16" />
                                        <bt:Image size="20" resid="Contoso.Supprimer_20x20" />
                                        <bt:Image size="24" resid="Contoso.Supprimer_24x24" />
                                        <bt:Image size="32" resid="Contoso.Supprimer_32x32" />
                                        <bt:Image size="40" resid="Contoso.Supprimer_40x40" />
                                        <bt:Image size="80" resid="Contoso.Supprimer_80x80" />
                                    </Icon>
                                    <Action xsi:type="ExecuteFunction">
                                        <FunctionName>action8</FunctionName>
                                    </Action>
                                </Item>                                 
                            </Items>
                        </Control>
                    </OfficeMenu>
                </ExtensionPoint>`
```